# Redux state.set resulting in undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

Can someone tell me why state.set is resulting in undefined.

I have a reducer like so:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  description: 'default_description',
});

function helpReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DEFAULT_ACTION:
      return state;
    case CHANGE_DESCRIPTION:
      console.log('Change Description reducer action.data: '+action.data); //results in string say foo
      console.log('state: '+state); //results in valid state on first call
      return state
        .set('description':action.data);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The first time I call the action CHANGE_DESCRIPTION, `state = default_description`.

After calling `state.set` the `state.description = undefined`.

I have used state.set before, but am unsure why it is failing now.

The action is being called by a child component like so:

Parent:

```
export class FOO extends React.PureComponent { 
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FOOForm onChange={this.props.changeDescription} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
    changeDescription: (e) => dispatch(changeDescription(e.target.value))
  };
}
```

Foo Form for sake of demonstration:

```
function fooForm(props){
 return <FormControl onChange={props.onChange} componentClass="textarea" />;

}
```

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code I would assume that action.data is undefined. Can you console.log `action.data` before the switch to see if it is holding what you want it to/

Comment: Action.data is definitely defined. When I console.log I get the correct value every time.

Comment: Why don't you just do ```return action.data```. It will automatically change reducer state. Like in documentation http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html

Comment: I think you need to use object.assign so you dont mutate the object
`return Object.assign({}, state, {
        visibilityFilter: action.filter
      }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the context in which you implement your reducer, but I believe the syntax in immutable JS should make your set look like this:

`return state.set('description', action.data)`

Note that you need to pass in the property and values as arguments and not as a key value pair.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help!